# Can't get remote Hazelcast client to connect to cluster running in docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, hazelcast

I've got a Hazelcast cluster running in docker containers using the discovery api with zookeeper. This all works fine and the cluster starts up and works as expected. My issue is connecting a client to the cluster from another server.

The cluster is returning 127.0.0.1 and 172.17.0.1 to zookeeper as it's cluster addresses, which means the client works fine running on the same machine but won't connect from a remote machine even with 172.17.0.1 mapped in the client's host file to the Hz cluster's server ip.

I've tried starting the containers with net=host and -h to get it to return an address I can map in the client's hosts file but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Below is the log and stack trace from the client

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/IdeaProjects/sandpit/datagrid/target/classes:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/IdeaProjects/sandpit/domain/target/classes:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-client/1.2.3/hbase-client-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-annotations/1.2.3/hbase-annotations-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/findbugs/findbugs-annotations/1.3.9-1/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-common/1.2.3/hbase-common-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-protocol/1.2.3/hbase-protocol-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/12.0.1/guava-12.0.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.23.Final/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jcodings/jcodings/1.0.8/jcodings-1.0.8.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/jruby/joni/joni/2.1.2/joni-2.1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.5.1/hadoop-auth-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.5.1/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.5.1/hadoop-annotations-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.5.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.5.1/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.5.1/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.7.2/hazelcast-all-3.7.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.10.0/curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.10.0/curator-client-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-x-discovery/2.10.0/curator-x-discovery-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.10.0/curator-recipes-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-test/2.10.0/curator-test-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-zookeeper/3.6.1/hazelcast-zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.example.datagrid.cachewarmer.CacheReader
2016-11-28 20:51:35 INFO  TradeMapStore:64 - Trying to connect to HBase
2016-11-28 20:51:35 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-11-28 20:51:37.473 java[25412:2402206] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  RecoverableZooKeeper:120 - Process identifier=hconnection-0x53443251 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=138.68.147.208:2181
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:host.name=172.20.10.2
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_45
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/IdeaProjects/sandpit/datagrid/target/classes:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/IdeaProjects/sandpit/domain/target/classes:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-client/1.2.3/hbase-client-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-annotations/1.2.3/hbase-annotations-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/findbugs/findbugs-annotations/1.3.9-1/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-common/1.2.3/hbase-common-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-protocol/1.2.3/hbase-protocol-1.2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/12.0.1/guava-12.0.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.23.Final/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jcodings/jcodings/1.0.8/jcodings-1.0.8.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/jruby/joni/joni/2.1.2/joni-2.1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.5.1/hadoop-auth-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.5.1/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.5.1/hadoop-annotations-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.5.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.5.1/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.5.1/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.7.2/hazelcast-all-3.7.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.10.0/curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.10.0/curator-client-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-x-discovery/2.10.0/curator-x-discovery-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.10.0/curator-recipes-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-test/2.10.0/curator-test-2.10.0.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-zookeeper/3.6.1/hazelcast-zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/sx/g9vbcw9d3j54gtj89n57g1fw0000gn/T/
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.arch=x86_64
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.version=10.11.6
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.name=oliverbuckley-salmon
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.home=/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.dir=/Users/oliverbuckley-salmon/IdeaProjects/sandpit
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ZooKeeper:438 - Initiating client connection, connectString=138.68.147.208:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x534432510x0, quorum=138.68.147.208:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server 138.68.147.208/138.68.147.208:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection established to 138.68.147.208/138.68.147.208:2181, initiating session
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server 138.68.147.208/138.68.147.208:2181, sessionid = 0x1583b2a4dbb0183, negotiated timeout = 90000
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  TradeMapStore:68 - Connected to HBase
2016-11-28 20:51:38 INFO  CacheReader:32 - Connecting to Hz cluster
Nov 28, 2016 8:51:38 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper
WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location incorrect using default
Nov 28, 2016 8:51:39 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is STARTING
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  CuratorFrameworkImpl:235 - Starting
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  ZooKeeper:438 - Initiating client connection, connectString=138.68.172.212:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@644fa139
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection established to 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181, initiating session
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181, sessionid = 0x15830869abd0077, negotiated timeout = 40000
2016-11-28 20:51:39 INFO  ConnectionStateManager:228 - State change: CONNECTED
Nov 28, 2016 8:51:40 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is STARTED
Nov 28, 2016 8:51:56 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
2016-11-28 20:52:07 INFO  ClientCnxn:1096 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 26671ms for sessionid 0x15830869abd0077, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-11-28 20:52:07 INFO  ConnectionStateManager:228 - State change: SUSPENDED
2016-11-28 20:52:09 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-11-28 20:52:09 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection established to 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181, initiating session
2016-11-28 20:52:09 INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server 138.68.172.212/138.68.172.212:2181, sessionid = 0x15830869abd0077, negotiated timeout = 40000
2016-11-28 20:52:09 INFO  ConnectionStateManager:228 - State change: RECONNECTED
Nov 28, 2016 8:52:25 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 2 of 2.
Nov 28, 2016 8:52:25 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is SHUTTING_DOWN
2016-11-28 20:52:25 INFO  CuratorFrameworkImpl:821 - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2016-11-28 20:52:25 INFO  ZooKeeper:684 - Session: 0x15830869abd0077 closed
2016-11-28 20:52:25 INFO  ClientCnxn:512 - EventThread shut down
Nov 28, 2016 8:52:25 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [kappa-serving-layer] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is SHUTDOWN
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried:[localhost/127.0.0.1:5703, /172.17.0.1:5701, /172.17.0.1:5702, /172.17.0.1:5703, localhost/127.0.0.1:5702, localhost/127.0.0.1:5701]
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:175)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:191)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:379)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientManager.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClientManager.java:78)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:72)
    at com.example.datagrid.cachewarmer.CacheReader.main(CacheReader.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Process finished with exit code 1
and the following is the command I'm using to launch the container

```
docker run -p 5701:5701 -ti --add-host=a826d5422c4d:138.68.147.208 --net=host -h muhz1 --name muhz1 -d olibs/kappahz:v0.1
```

The add host is to map the Zookeeper for Hbase which I'm using as an underlying database for Hz, this works fine.

Thanks in advance for your help, any hints or tips gratefully received.
Oliver

Comment: A few Hazelcast employees monitor the hazelcast tag (I'm not one of them), but to be helpful, you might want to add the contents of the `<discovery-strategies>` section of both your client and server-side hazelcast.xml (or hazelcast-client.xml) files to your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
My issue is connecting a client to the cluster from another server.
```

I don't know much about Zookeeper but I can help you with that.

First, you need to know which network you share between the client and the server. You can use `ifconfig` for this purpose.

Then you need to know the IP address of the server that hosts your Hazelcast cluster containers (as you use `host` network mode of docker - which means your container uses the host's network interfaces directly). Again, you can get this by using `ifconfig`. Let's assume it is `192.168.1.27`.

When you're starting your Hazelcast cluster using docker containers, you can expose it by using this IP and a port of your choice as follows:

```
docker run -it --net=host --name hz1 -p 192.168.1.27:5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
```

Add another node to the cluster if you want:

```
docker run -it --net=host --name hz2 -p 192.168.1.27:5702:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
```

Now you can point your Hazelcast client to either `192.168.1.27:5701` or `192.168.1.27:5701` and it will connect to the cluster. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give it a try

Comment: Hi, I've tried but still get the same result, with Zookeeper still returning > `The following addresses were tried:[localhost/127.0.0.1:5703, /172.17.0.1:5701, /172.17.0.1:5702, localhost/127.0.0.1:5702, localhost/127.0.0.1:5701` > I just need to be able to get Zookeeper to return either the host or a mappable ip address. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear above, it's not Zookeeper returning that, it's the error message from the Hz client.  The problem is that Zookeeper won't return.  I'll ask the Hz Zookeeepr project.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have most everything correct so I would check the dockerfile for an expose 5701 / also you might want to expose a range (:8000-9000:8000-9000) and then specify that same range as the outbound port range in the hazelcast config.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try